# Windows implementation of keepalivd?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, failover, keepalived

Me and my team have been trying to find a solution to the following setup:

Two physical/vm machines with their own memory and network devices. One will act as master the other slave. A virtual IP will point to the Master only and in the event that a) Master goes down or b) and application on Master goes down we would like for the virtual IP to point over towards the Slave which will then take on the role as Master until the original Master restarts or fixes the application and which will then retake the Master position and then point the virtual IP to itself again.

In Linux this can be done via keepalived. I have yet to see how this is done on a Windows 2016 machine?

Comment: Failover Clustering? It's a server role.

Comment: like @duenni says - Windows Clustering

Comment: @duenni We looked into it and we just cannot get any information regarding it. It referred us to the Windows 2012 guide which states that the failover clustering is for *shared memory*. We need two identical instances of the server running in their own memory. If you could provide some documentation I would call that an answer to my question!

Comment: Set reverse proxy in front of these machines. Haproxy, Netscaler, IIS ARR, etc.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/failover-clustering-overview